# How to copy 5 newest files from one directory to another and delete the old copies

Tags: shell, file-copy, timestamps

How can I copy the 5 newest files from a directory to another in a "new to old" order.

Comment: There's a discrepancy between the subject and body of your question. Please clarify what you mean by "delete the old copies". Do you want to move those files?

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
cp -- *(om[1,5]) /dest/dir
```

Or:

```
cp -- *(.om[1,5]) /dest/dir
```

To limit to regular files only.

With `bash` or `ksh93` and GNU `ls`:

```
eval "sorted_files=($(ls -t --quoting-style=shell-always))"
cp -- "${sorted_files[@]:0:5}" /dest/dir
```

(note that those ignore hidden files. Add the `D` globbing qualifier, or the `-A` option to `ls` to include them).

To delete the 5 older ones, same in reverse order:

```
rm -- *(.Om[1,5])
```

(note the `O` instead of `o`). Or:

```
eval "sorted_files=($(ls -rt --quoting-style=shell-always))"
rm -- "${sorted_files[@]:0:5}"
```

(note the `-r`)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming filenames don't contain newline characters:

```
IFS='
'
set -f
for i in `ls -t /path/to/sourcedirectory | head -n 5`
do
  cp "/path/to/sourcedirectory/$i" /path/to/destdirectory/
done
```

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that the file names do not contain newlines in them:

```
ls -t | head -n5 | while IFS= read -r fname
do
    cp -- "$fname" newdir/
done
```

If, in addition, you want to delete the old copies, then use `mv` in place of `cp`:

```
ls -t | head -n5 | while IFS= read -r fname
do
    mv -- "$fname" newdir/
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Well from the answers above, assuming the similar condition incase file names do not contain newlines in them:

```
ls -t | head -n5 | xargs -I{} mv {} $destination_dir
```

This would do.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all files except the 5 newest ones:

```
find -type f -printf '%T@ %P\n' | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2- | head -n -5 | xargs rm
```

You can easily adapt it to later copy/move files somewhere else.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190845/trying-to-delete-all-but-most-recent-2-files-in-sub-directories